# Python cant see files or folders in C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy

Tags: windows, python-2.7, redirect, 32bit-64bit

I'm running into a problem where python is unable to see folders or files which do exist on the computer.  I have already ensured the path has no symbolic links in it and that I have full control on the NTFS file permissions.  I have even removed any hidden attributes.  Below is the script I am using and its output:

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine'
print path
test = os.path.exists(path)
print test

C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine
False
```

I am unsure why it is returning False when I have ensured the folder does exist.  If I remove "\Machine" from the path, it returns True.  I have verified the following command works from a command prompt:

```
if exist c:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine echo found
```

Any advice on how to get this working in python would be appreciated.  Here is the version of python I am using:
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Answer (score 6):

Alright, after some digging, found it is nothing to do with permissions but has to do with File System Redirection.  As I am using the x86 version of python on a Windows x64 (using x86 as I am using py2exe), Windows is redirecting any queries on System32 and subdirectories to SysWOW64.  This means I was actually querying "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\GroupPolicy\Machine" which did not exist.

To fix this, I found how to disable the File System redirection using the recipe found here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578035-disable-file-system-redirector/

Here is my final code which now works to disable the redirection and allows opening and querying of files in System32 on a 64 bit machine.

```
import ctypes
class disable_file_system_redirection:
    _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
    _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
        self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.success:
            self._revert(self.old_value)


disable_file_system_redirection().__enter__()
import os
path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine'
print path
test = os.path.exists(path)
print test
```

Comment: +1 I had a similar issue only that i was creating files in System32/ras through rpyc on a remote machine but the files were never created. After reading your answer i took a look at SysWOW64 and indeed the files were there.